# Mouse events with Raphael.js are triggered by any mouse button

Tags: javascript

I am using raphael.js to manipulate images inside a "paper". I have realized that all mouse events (click, mousedown, mouseup, dragstart...) are triggered by any mouse button.

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jecs9/m1d57ujg/) there is an example to drag two objects, it is possible to drag them around with left, right or middle mouse buttons

```
JSFiddle
```

How can I filter the events depending on which button was clicked? For instance, I would like to drag only with the left mouse button

I have read in another StackOverflow post that it is possible to identify the mouse button with e.which, it will return 1, 2, or 3 depending on the pressed button but I cannot find a way to use this variable to filter the event triggers.

I have found a [Bug report](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/561) about this issue but it is open since 2012. I have tried to use part of the code to filter the mouse button with if(e.which == 1) and then I made a console entry. In this way the console entry only appears when I attempt to make a drag with the left button, it won't appear with the other buttons. I have not found a way to implement the rest of the code

Does anybody know what is g.doc.documentElement or g.doc.body (From the bug report code)?

Thank you in advance for your support

Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it, instead of installing raphael using npm install raphael I have downloaded the js file from github and then edited the drag function in the following way:

```
elproto.drag = function (onmove, onstart, onend, move_scope, start_scope, end_scope) {
        function start(e) {
            if (e.which == 1) {
                (e.originalEvent || e).preventDefault();
                var x = e.clientX,
                    y = e.clientY,
                    scrollY = g.doc.documentElement.scrollTop || g.doc.body.scrollTop,
                    scrollX = g.doc.documentElement.scrollLeft || g.doc.body.scrollLeft;
                this._drag.id = e.identifier;
                if (supportsTouch && e.touches) {
                    var i = e.touches.length, touch;
                    while (i--) {
                        touch = e.touches[i];
                        this._drag.id = touch.identifier;
                        if (touch.identifier == this._drag.id) {
                            x = touch.clientX;
                            y = touch.clientY;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                this._drag.x = x + scrollX;
                this._drag.y = y + scrollY;
                !drag.length && R.mousemove(dragMove).mouseup(dragUp);
                drag.push({el: this, move_scope: move_scope, start_scope: start_scope, end_scope: end_scope});
                onstart && eve.on("raphael.drag.start." + this.id, onstart);
                onmove && eve.on("raphael.drag.move." + this.id, onmove);
                onend && eve.on("raphael.drag.end." + this.id, onend);
                eve("raphael.drag.start." + this.id, start_scope || move_scope || this, this._drag.x, this._drag.y, e);
            }
        }
        this._drag = {};
        draggable.push({el: this, start: start});
        this.mousedown(start);
        return this;
    };
```

This works fine, I have to do the same for each mouse event but I think the information would be helpful for someone else.